# php header status description

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

Just setting up a super simple API for something but I have a question.
I'm calling the api, and it works perfectly, but I'm wondering about the header status code that's being return.

On all errors, I want to set the error to 500:

```
header('HTTP 1.1 500 invalid signature');
```

It's the description I'm curious about. Is there a way to grab that text using CuRL?
I can get the code no problem, not the text.

Or can someone recommend and easier way of throwing a status of 500, and passing a string back through to the api file that can show what error happened?

Comment: Take a look at curl_error function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: doesnt work because the url is still being loaded, so it returns as ok

Comment: If it is an API I suggest you don't need the response body for any data? So you could put your error/description string there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would use some other custom header for status message:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
header('My-Super-Custom-Error-Msg: invalid signature');
```

Comment: "As far as I am concerned text that comes after the status code is fixed by the HTTP 1.1 standard."

This seems to be addressed in the standard:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1
"... an example set of corresponding Reason-Phrase's, are presented below. The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol"

Comment: Thanks a lot for noting this Josh. I was wrong indeed. I removed my false assumptions from answer.

Answer (score 1):

cURL returns the complete response including headers when you set `CURLOPT_HEADER` option. The header and content are separated by two CRLF; the headers themselves are separated using CRLF. This information should be enough for you to parse the status header from the response:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/err-500.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
$header = explode("\r\n", $header);

echo $header[0];
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

If you are interested in throwing an error, your script can emit the `500` response status plus a custom header with a single line of code:

Or you can use the [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to set the response code:

```
header("X-Error-Message: Invalid Signature", true, 500);
```

PHP fills in the `1.1` and `Internal Server Error` portions of the status line:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Error-Message: Invalid Signature
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 21:11:00 GMT
Content-Length: 100
```